# UnKnown height is being applied to pre tag

Tags: html, css

I have a set of pre-tags on a webpage. These pre-tags have a 60px height by default which I am not able to figure out where they are comings from.

Here is the page that is having the issue -> https://dsabyte.com/blog/engineering/programming/java-script/Sleep-Function-In-JavaScript--AsyncSync-47b91c1e-8d39-4993-bd7a-a2d12ae11a3e#gRNOP0dVww

[image]

I deleted every child element of the `pre` tag, but still `pre` tag has a 60px height.
Then after I removed the class name and inline styles to see the effect still `pre` tag still had a 60px height. Below is the screenshot for the same...

[image: dsabyte]

I also tried looking at the classes and CSS on the right side, but couldn’t find anything which could cause this issue.

Can someone help me here?

Thanks in advance!

#### Edit

Here is the inline CSS being applied on `pre` tag

```css
padding: 10px; background-color: #232428; color: white; overflow: scroll;
```

Comment: Have you given the pre tag any height? The 60px might be coming from the height needed by the browser to display the text since you didn't give it any specific height.

Comment: Please extract just enough code to show the problem and put it direct into your question as your question will become useless to future readers once your website is debugged.

Comment: @AHaworth I don’t which part of the code is having the issue and it's not possible to post the entire code of the website itself. But surely, I'll update the post with a code example once issue is figured out.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre tag renders white spaces as well, you can use css property **whitespace** to make sure that whitespaces are trimmed while representation.

1. For example giving **whitespace**: pre-line to pre tag in your case removes the extra spacing from top and bottom of your code block.

[Post adding this css this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3d4g.png)

2. Or you can just give **display**: flex to pre tag

[Post adding **display**: flex css this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3d4g.png)

Comment: `display:flex` worked, thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can set `height: fit-content;` to pre tags in CSS.

Comment: Sorry, but this did not work. you can see the screenshot here https://imgur.com/a/cfdzYUU and if you want to debug then please open this site. https://dsabyte.com/blog/engineering/programming/java-script/Sleep-Function-In-JavaScript--AsyncSync-47b91c1e-8d39-4993-bd7a-a2d12ae11a3e